# How to add an external link inside form actions?

Tags: forms, actions

I want to programmatically add an external link next to my submit button in a form that I have created.

Comment: If you consider that my question has not been correctly formulated is fine and therefore I understand the downvotes, but if you do want help next time, add a comment at least explaining why my question is wrong...

Comment: People are explicitly discouraged from commenting on downvotes - I'm sure this won't be the case for you personally, but it too often leads to name-calling and revenge voting, which messes up the site. If you hover over the downvote arrow you'll see a tooltip explaining the general reason, which I think it's fair to say does apply here

Comment: @Clive I didn't know about that feature and that it was discouraged, so thanks for you comment!

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was adding a link element within the actions array

```
$form['actions']['google_search'] = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => $this->t('Google Search'),
      '#url' => Url::fromUri('https://www.google.com/search?whatever'),
      '#attributes' => ['target' => '_blank', 'class'=> 'button'],
    ];
```

Ps: Directly adding the url to the #url element does not work, I had to use the Url component